# Navigating multiples files vi editor

Tags: linux, unix, editor, vi

According to http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi2.html
the command `:p` would make vi go to the previous file. Unfortunately, this isn't working for me. However `:n` works and goes to the next page. What should I use to go to the previous file?
For `:p` I get the message,

`Hit Return to continue`

and it stays in the same page.
Thanks.

Edit:
I am sshing to an AIX box and using the vi in Ksh if that helps.
Edit 2:
Looks like rewinding to first is possible with `:rew` but listing all the files with `:ar` results in the same message,

`Hit Return to continue`

May be this isn't possible at all from all the vi tutorials I've read so far including,
http://www.bo.infn.it/alice/alice-doc/mll-doc/linux/vi-ex/node27.html

Comment: A lot of answers here tend to give solutions for `vim` while you seem to use `vi`. If you don't want to or can't switch to `vim`, i suggest you remove the `vim` tag from your question, as it would then be very misleading.

Comment: Ok. I thought vim users probably would have used vi before as it is "Vi improved"

Comment: I wish I did so I would know all the differences between the two. But I believe a lot of people using `Vim` never used `Vi` before. At least in the some I know.

Comment: @learner125: vim was initially released in '91, at a time when many of us were just tots. :)  So, a great many people have just gone straight to vim, as vi offers no real benefit over it.

Comment: I don't think you can move backwards through a list of files in the original vi. I think you could move to the previously file (edited & viewed both), rewind, or move to the next file. See my answer below for more.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Vim's help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html), `:N` (uppercase!) should be legal vi to go back a file:

```
:[count]n[ext] [++opt] [+cmd]           *:n* *:ne* *:next* *E165* *E163*
            Edit [count] next file.  This fails when changes have
            been made and Vim does not want to |abandon| the
            current buffer.  Also see |++opt| and |+cmd|.  {Vi: no
            count or ++opt}.


:[count]N[ext] [count] [++opt] [+cmd]           *:Next* *:N* *E164*
            Edit [count] previous file in argument list.  This
            fails when changes have been made and Vim does not
            want to |abandon| the current buffer.
            Also see |++opt| and |+cmd|.  {Vi: no count or ++opt}.
```

Comment: That doesn't work too. Maybe because I am using vi and not vim.

Comment: @learner: What version of vi are you using?  Is it possibly a non-compliant or otherwise non-standard version?

Comment: I don't know. Is there a command to find that? I am using the default vi present in AIX 5.3 which is not very old I guess. Edit: (AIX 5.3 was released 2004, acc to wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX)

Comment: @learner135: if you start vi with no file it should give you some version information. At least, it does on my system were vi actually starts vim.

Answer (score 1):

According to the vi manual page from AIX 5.2, this isn't possible:

```
Editing a List of Files: Enter the following subcommands in command mode. If you
need information about the format of vi subcommands, see ″vi General Subcommand
Syntax.″
:n             Edits the next file in the list entered on the command line. If
               you are using this subcommand from the ex editor, a : (colon) is
               not needed.
:n Files       Specifies a new list of files to edit. If you are using this
               subcommand from the ex editor, a : (colon) is not needed.
```

Check the vi manual (man vi) on your system, maybe it's been updated in AIX 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Tried :bn, :bp ?

Comment: Yep I did!No gain. It was suggested by another user who later decided to delete it for some reason. I get "Not an editor command" message for that.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake user :prev or :previous